# Multiple Citations without outer parentheses

Tags: bibtex, citing

Using the AAAI style [included here](http://www.aaai.org/Publications/Templates/AuthorKit.zip) [and detailed here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEMQFjAC&url=http://www.icwsm.org/2010/aaai-style.pdf&ei=JwxjUeSVKdO30gH0n4DQBQ&usg=AFQjCNH6Jip6fNeewYDxnTkSyVgTj-pWag&sig2=QpNkxPUIs6_WevD88QwF_g&bvm=bv.44770516,d.dmQ), when I cite several authors like so:

```
\cite{X,Y,Z}
```

I get:

```
(Xauthor, Xyear; Yauthor, Yyear; Zauthor, Zyear)
```

when I cite like so:

```
\citealt{X,Y,Z}
```

I get:

```
XauthorYear; YauthorYear; ZauthorYear
```

Is there a way to cite without those outer parens? So that I can achieve

```
Yada yada yada (e.g., Xauthor, Xyear; Yauthor, Yyear; Zauthor, Zyear)
```

instead of

```
Yada yada yada (e.g., (Xauthor, Xyear; Yauthor, Yyear; Zauthor, Zyear))
```

or

```
Yada yada yada (e.g., (XauthorYear; YauthorYear; ZauthorYear))
```

The only solution I can find is to do

```
\citeauthor{xcitation} \citeyear{xcitation}, \citeauthor{ycitation}  \citeyear{ycitation}, \citeauthor{zcitation} \citeyear{zcitation}
```

But it seems like there *has* to be a more efficient way to accomplish this.

(NOTE: As mentioned in the comments below, the solution accepted for this answer involves using natbib, a package explicitly forbidden when submitting to the AAAI conference. If you actually need to submit a document to the AAAI conference, this page does not contain an answer for you.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: If you have access to `natbib`'s capabilities (which seems to be the case here, according to a comment), you can use `\citetext` and `\citealt` or `\citealp`:
`\citetext{e.g., \citealt{X}, \citealt{Y}, \citealt{Z}}`. (I deleted my answer and moved it to a comment).

Comment: @williamstome then please edit your question and add a minimal, yet complete document showing the relevant settings; in particular, provide a link to the AAAI style (I assume it's a .bst file) you mentioned.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I hadn't used natbib before, and thus did not realize it was a separate package I needed to import. From your answer, I thought I already had access to the capabilities you listed. Reading the natbib documentation elucidated my situation.

Comment: @williamstome That's why I insisted so eagerly on your current settings: I assumed that you were already using `natbib`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Understood. Sorry for that mix up and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `natbib` package by adding in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

and then, according to [natbib documentation](http://ftp.oleane.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf) when you use:

`\citeauthor*{jon90}` --> Jones, Baker, and Williams

`\citet*{jon90}` --> Jones, Baker, and Williams (1990)

`\citep*{jon90}` --> (Jones, Baker, and Williams, 1990)

`\citealt{jon90}` --> Jones, Baker, and Williams, 1990

Comment: Solution:
In preamble:
\usepackage{natbib}
In rest of paper:
For normal citations use \citep.
For the types of citations this question refers to, use \citealt.

Comment: @williamstome, It was hard to know what you exactly wanted, that's why please next time make sure to completely address your issue and what are you expecting as an answer :)

Comment: For others who happen on this thread, the AAAI publisher explicitly forbids `natbib` for submitted papers. Please be aware before using this package if you are actually using this style for a published paper.

Comment: `\citealt{jon90}` doesn't have a comma, `\citealp{jon90}` does. https://gking.harvard.edu/files/natnotes2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

According to the instructions provided with the AAAI author kit the use of the natbib package is disallowed. They write that if you use it...

> [...] your references will be garbled and your paper will
>   be returned to you.

As a workaround they recommend:

> If you used natbib commands, an imprecise workaround is available (although it does not always work). You may put the following in your preamble (after removing \usepackage{natbib}
>
> ```
> \newcommand{\citet}[1]{\citeauthor{#1} \shortcite{#1}}
> \newcommand{\citep}{\cite}
> \newcommand{\citealp}[1]{\citeauthor{#1} \citeyear{#1}}
> ```